# How to get first row of pandas pivot as list?

Tags: python, pandas

I create my dataframe and pivot as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'country': ['US','US','US','US','US','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','IT','IT','IT','IT','IT'],
'dimension': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e'],
'count': [29, 10, 9, 34,29, 10, 9, 34,29, 10, 9, 34,15,17,18],
})
```

Pivot:

```
pivoted = df.pivot_table(index='country', columns='dimension', values='count')
```

[image]

Now I want to get the values of the first row of pivot to list? How to do?

Output in a list should be: 9, 34, 15, 17, 18

I tried iloc but did not succeed.

Answer (score 2):

```
print(pivoted.iloc[0,:].tolist()) # [9, 34, 15, 17, 18]
```